# AS3 Object vs. Dictionary

Tags: actionscript-3, string, object, dictionary

I'm often seeing others using a Dictionary object in their AS3 code that simply maps objects by String keys and wondering if there is any advantage at all of using a Dictionary over a simple Object if String keys are used. Anyone know any details on this? I would suppose that since an Object is more lightweight it should be faster and preferable over a Dictionary if used with String keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, if you use string keys, there is no need to use the Dictionary class.

Answer (score 2):

AS3 dictionary objects use up less memory. I'll suggest you use a dictionary object if you plan to store a large number of objects.

The following is a benchmark snippet from: http://www.zombieflambe.com/as3/as3-dictionary-class-array-object-benchmark/

```
Create Time      
Array 0.224 ms  Object 0.873 ms Dictionary 0.286 ms

Search Time      
Array 0.006 ms  Object 0.234 ms  Dictionary 0.000 ms

Total Memory Used    

Array 16512     Object 17380    Dictionary  5328
```

Comment: I'm not sure that it uses less memory, it just aids in garbage collection if you use weak keys.